# Django email

Tags: python, django, email, django-email

I am using the Gmail SMTP server to send out emails from users of my website.

These are the default settings in my settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

If I want a user to send an email, I am overriding these settings and sending the email using Django's email sending methods. When an exception occurs in the system, I receive an email from the example@example.com. Sometimes I receive an email from some logged in user. Which could also possibly mean that when a user receives an email sent from my website it has a sent address different from the actual user.

What should be done to avoid this situation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Django only uses **settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL** when any of the mail sending functions pass `None` or empty string as the *sender address*.  This can be verified in `django/core/mail.py`.

When there is an unhandled exception Django calls the `mail_admins()` function in `django/core/mail.py` which always uses **settings.SERVER_EMAIL** and is **only** sent to addresses listed in **settings.ADMINS**.  This can also be verified in `django/core/mail.py`.

The only other place Django itself sends e-mails is if **settings.SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS** is True, then CommonMiddleware will send mail to all addresses listed in **settings.MANAGERS** and the e-mail sender is **settings.SERVER_EMAIL**.

Therefore, the only time a regular user will receive e-mail from your site is when you call `send_mail()`.  So, always pass a real address as the `from_mail` argument and you will avoid users receiving email from **settings.SERVER_EMAIL** or **settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL**.

Side note: django-registration is at least one example of a Django pluggable that will send mail from **settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL** so in cases like this you need to make sure it is a proper e-mail address such as support@yoursite.com or webmaster@yoursite.com.

Comment: You are a hero !